# semantics of first order logic - when defining structure

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

So say L is a structure, which has constant, function and predicate symbols C, F and P.

An L-structure S = (D, I) gives meaning to symbols in C, F and P.
• D is a set — the domain of the structure S.
• I interprets the constant function and predicate symbols. So I
has three parts I = (Ic, If,Ip).

Up to here I have no problem understanding.

However, I do not understand the following definitions.

```
 Ic : C -> D
 If(f^n) : D^n -> D
 Ip(r^n) ⊆ D^n
```

I am confused about the meaning of ":" and "->". how does ic : C entails D, where D is a set? I kept googling but I still could not find explanations for these definitions.

Comment: The symbol $f : C \to D$ means : "$f$ is a function (a *map*) *from* (set) $C$ *to* (set) $D$".

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal L$ is the *language* with a set $C$ of *constants* symbols, a set  $F$ of *function* symbols and a set $P$ of *predicate* symbols.

The $\mathcal L$-structure $S= \langle D, I \rangle$ is made of a set $D$, the *domain* and a set $I = \{ I_C, I_F, I_P \}$ of *functions*, where e.g.:

> $I_C : C \to D$

is the function that interpret the *constant* symbols; it assign to each constant $c$ of the language $\mathcal L$ an object of the domain $D$, usually denoted as $c^S$.

For example, if $\mathcal L$ is the first-order language of arithmetic, with constant $0$, functions $+$ and $\times$ and predicate $<$, and we interpret it with the domain $\mathbb N$ of *natural* numbers, then the function $I_C$ will assign to the symbol $0$ the *number* $\text {zero}$.

In the same way, the symbol $+$ is mapped by $I_F$ to a binary *operation* in $\mathbb N$, i.e.:

> $+^{\mathbb N} : \mathbb N^2 \to \mathbb N$

i.e. the $\text {sum}$ operation.

Thus, we have that $I_F(+)=+^{\mathbb N}$, i.e. the "interpreting" function $I_F$ maps the symbol $+$ (a binary function symbol) into the $\text{sum}$ operation on *natural* numbers.

The same for the binary predicate symbol $<$; the interpretation $I_P$ maps it into the (binary) relation $\text {less than}$: a bianry relation on $\mathbb N$ is a subset of $\mathbb N^2$.